# Annotate city names

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, contextily

I would like to annotate the city name Berlin at the coordinates `xy=(52.52, 13.405)`. I've tried `ax.annotate()` which yields a strange map. Maybe it has to do with the CRS of the coordinates?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import contextily as ctx

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world = world[(world.name=="Germany")]
world = world.to_crs(epsg=3857)

ax = world.plot(figsize=(10, 10), color='none', linewidth=1, alpha=0.5)
ax.annotate("Berlin", xy=(52.52, 13.405))

ctx.add_basemap(ax, url=ctx.providers.Stamen.Watercolor, zoom=9)
```

[image]

Comment: Not familiar with `geopandas` but in `matplotlib.pyplot` the syntax of `annotate` is `ax.annotate('text',(x,y))`. I guess `geopandas` is written over `matplotlib`. Try this `ax.annotate('Berlin',xy)`

Answer (score 2):

According to [Annotations docpage](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/text/annotations.html) your code should look like this:

```
ax.annotate("Berlin", xy=(52.52, 13.405))
```

Comment: Does not worl. Maybe it has to do with the CRS of the coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

My initial code was flawed in two ways. I wrongly used `ax.annoate()` as pointed out by other answers.

In addition, `world` was transformed to `espg=3857`. The coordinates of the city Berlin weren't. With transformed coordinates it works:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import contextily as ctx

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world = world[(world.name=="Germany")]
world = world.to_crs(epsg=3857)

ax = world.plot(figsize=(10, 10), color='none', linewidth=1, alpha=0.5)
ax.annotate("Berlin", xy=(1491636.9565986055, 6895388.533179172))

ctx.add_basemap(ax, url=ctx.providers.Stamen.Watercolor, zoom=9)
```

[image]